# Python - web crawling / different result from same code? / requests, bs4 / M1

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I learning python for web crawling, but i'm totally stuck.

Each time I run this codes, results change.

very rarely, it works but almost return empty list.

why does it happen? please let me know

```
from indeed import extract_indeed_pages, extract_indeed_jobs


last_indeed_page = extract_indeed_pages()

print(last_indeed_page)

indeed_jobs = extract_indeed_jobs(last_indeed_page)

print(indeed_jobs)
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LIMIT = 50
URL = f"https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=React&l=%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8&radius=100&jt=fulltime&limit={LIMIT}"


def extract_indeed_pages():
    result = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    pagination = soup.find("div", {"class": "pagination"})

    links = pagination.find_all('a')
    pages = []
    for link in links[:-1]:
        pages.append(int(link.string))

    max_page = pages[-1]
    return max_page


def extract_indeed_jobs(last_page):

    jobs = []
    
    result = requests.get(f"{URL}&start={0*LIMIT}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "jobTitle"})
    jobs.append(results)

    return jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the javascript on the source code. You can view the web page by pressing the `ctrl + u` buttons on your pc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i can't get it. please explain more details. is there a JS code in my code? where should i press crtl+U? in visual studio code? or terminal?